# Aligning a \marginnote to a theorem title

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ntheorem, marginnote

I want to create a `\marginnote` which is aligned to the title of a theorem. However, the `\marginnote` is always placed over or under the title, when I put the `\marginnote` command before or into the `theorem` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[my title]
    \marginnote{my comment}
    my definition
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[my title]
    \marginnote{my comment}[-\baselineskip]% Adjust the vertical offset here
    my definition
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Note that

> The command `\marginnote[<left>]{<right>}[<voffset>]` may be used to
>   set a margin note using marginnote. The first optional argument and the
>   mandatory argument are same using `\marginpar` from the LATEX kernel.
>   Even `\reversemarginpar` will be considered. The note `<left>` or `<right>`
>   will be put at the current vertical position. Second optional argument
>   `<voffset>` may be used to adjust the vertical position of the margin
>   note. Use a negative dimension to move it up or a positive dimension
>   to move it down.